# Missing doc comment errors

Tags: error, filetype-php

Just started to look into VIM for my coding. I managed to set up some functionality with pathogen and want to make a slow start to learn VIM. the problem is that when I open a PHP document, I get swamped with the warning "Missing doc comment"

Of course for good practice these comments should be in the file, but when just playing around this is annoying. Is there a way to turn (toggle) this off?

Any other tips welcome, but I am just getting my feet wet in VIM

**Edit: My current plugins:**

auto-pairs , nerdtree , supertab , syntastic , vim-autoformat , vim-jsbeautify , vim-sensible

Comment: If you have Vim 8 then you don't need pathogen anymore. Read `:h packages` for more info. BTW. `:help` is the most useful command in Vim.

Comment: The message is probably shown by one of the plugins you installed. Check [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) to find out which plugin is doing that and then check the doc of the plugin to see if you can disable this behavior.

Comment: so what plugins have you installed?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt = I have added the list of plugins. I will run VIM without plugins and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: OK ,,, That was simple enough. (facepalm) .. It is clean now. I will find out which one it was and read up some. At least I am learning and not drowning in errors. And implement plugins more carefully.

Comment: @statox - Can you add your solution. Your description fits the issue.

Comment: @Daniel Even more helpful to future readers would be if you wrote up your own answer once you've tracked down which plugin caused the issue and whether it's possible to avoid the behaviour without entirely removing the plugin. Glad you've managed to sort out the original problem!

Comment: @Daniel I will not write my comment as an answer because that basically means that your question is a duplicate of "How do I debug my vimrc". You can either follow Rich's suggestion to write an answer about which plugin caused a problem and how you can configure it to avoid that, or close your question as a duplicate

Comment: @statox - fair enough. Will do so.

Answer (score 1):

Being a beginner of VIM it may be tempting to install plugin candy, but caution is in place.

With Pathogen, plugins get installed in ~/vim/bundle
First thing I tried is to zip all the plugins and delete their originals. This quick dirty step already fixed the main issue. My first assumption was the Syntastic plugin.

Looking up this plugin and the toggle I was looking for, led me to this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030603/vim-syntastic-how-to-disable-the-checker

Using `:SyntasticToggleMode` will do the trick, but do check out the post, which has some tips as well.